# Data warehouse backup strategy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, data-warehouse

I have a data warehouse development environment.

Just as the production environment. it loads data every night from test OLTP databases.

I want a backup every time the load process finishes.

What is the best backup strategy?

Comment: David has the right answer below. Just add a backup to the end of the ETL process. Its a data warehouse and a development one at that. It should be running in simple recovery mode and it sounds like the scope of the data and usefulness of the backup is a single day - therefore the only model you need to consider is a daily full backup.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on a great many things:

- How large is the database
- How much changes in each ETL process (practically all of it? Only 10%?, ...)
- As an extension to the above: does the stuff that doesn't change remain in place, or does your load process wipe everything and re-import instead of just importing changes? (if so then even if only a small % changes effectively everything changes)
- How much growth is there expected in the data over time (some percentage per month? some number of Gb per day?)
- How long do you need to retain the backups?
- What space do you have?
- Do you have any existing constrains on the recovery models you can use?
- How are you running the data loads?

The simplest option, which may be useful or may not depending on the above questions, if you are using SSIS to manage the data loading, is to add a full backup to the end of the process in SSIS. Without much more detail in your question there are probably thousands of options/combinations we could suggest.

Comment: I think This siss option sounds good.

Comment: Backups need to be made at least once a day.